# Node.js unzip file with non-ascii file names

Tags: node.js, encoding, zip

I'm trying to uncompress a zip file containing files whose names are not ascii(Korean, Japanese..etc)

I've tried `adm-zip, node-zip, unzip` libraries and they all give me 
`Invalid CEN header (bad signature)`  error.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The [zip module](https://npmjs.org/package/zip) (which actually unzips) supports different character sets. I've used it for filenames containing UTF-8 characters.